# multithreaded TcpServer in C# not working properly

Tags: c#

I am new to multithreading in C# and i have experienced this problem from following tutorials online

This is my server

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading;

namespace CoreEngine
{
    class MultithreadedTCP
    {
        private TcpListener myListener;
        private Thread ListenThread;

    public MultithreadedTCP()
    {
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CoreEngineIP"]);
        myListener = new TcpListener(ip, Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CoreEnginePort"]));
        this.ListenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
        this.ListenThread.Start();
    }

    private void ListenForClients()
    {
        this.myListener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = this.myListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
            clientThread.Start(client);
        }
    }

    private void HandleClientComm(object client)
    {
        TcpClient Tcpclient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream clientStream = Tcpclient.GetStream();
        byte[] message = new byte[4096];
        while (true)
        {
            //send all data here
            clientStream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("client connected : " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message, 0, message.Length));
            //break;
        }

    }
}
```

}

This is my client code. I stimulated 4 client connecting to this server

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Configuration.Assemblies;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class Client
    {
        public void send(String args)
        {
            TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient();
            TcpClient tcp1 = new TcpClient();
            TcpClient tcp2 = new TcpClient();
            TcpClient tcp3 = new TcpClient();
            tcp.Connect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CoreEngineIP"], Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CoreEnginePort"]));
            tcp1.Connect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CoreEngineIP"], Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CoreEnginePort"]));
            tcp2.Connect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CoreEngineIP"], Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CoreEnginePort"]));
            tcp3.Connect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CoreEngineIP"], Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CoreEnginePort"]));

            args = "client 0";
            Stream str = tcp.GetStream();
            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] b = asen.GetBytes(args);
            str.Write(b, 0, b.Length);

            args = "client 1";
            Stream str1 = tcp1.GetStream();
            ASCIIEncoding asen1 = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] b1 = asen.GetBytes(args);
            str.Write(b1, 0, b.Length);

            args = "client 2";
            Stream str2 = tcp2.GetStream();
            ASCIIEncoding asen2 = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] b2 = asen.GetBytes(args);
            str.Write(b2, 0, b.Length);

            args = "client 3";
            Stream str3 = tcp3.GetStream();
            ASCIIEncoding asen3 = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] b3 = asen.GetBytes(args);
            str.Write(b3, 0, b.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Output: Client Connected: Client 0 Client 1 Client 2 Client 3

Expected Output: 
Client Connected: Client 0 
Client Connected : Client 1
Client Connected: Client 2
Client Connected: client 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the first client's `str.Write` in each block.

However this demonstrates a 2nd problem you did not account for, `Read(` does not read the same amount `Write(` put on the wire. All 4 connect messages got combined in to a single `Read`.

You need to develop some form of "Message Protocol" to signify where one message stops and one begins. The easiest way to do it is prepend the length of the message before you send your message.

Client Side

```
args = "client 0";
Stream str = tcp.GetStream();
ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] b = asen.GetBytes(args);
if(b.Length > 255)
    throw new InvalidDataException("Messages must have a length less than 256");
str.WriteByte((byte)b.Length);
str.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
```

Server Side

```
byte[] message = new byte[256]; //This can now be 256 as that is the most messageLength can be.
while (true)
{
    //get the length of the message
    int messageLength = clientStream.ReadByte();
    if(messageLength == -1)
        break;

    // "Read(" can read less than the total length you requested, so you must loop till you have the entire message.
    int offset = 0;
    while(offset < messageLength)
    {
        offset += clientStream.Read(message, offset, messageLength - offest);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("client connected : " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message, 0, message.Length));
}
```

If you wanted to send messages larger than 255 bytes you could but you would need to design the protocal around that. For example you could write to the network stream `str.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(b.Length), 0, 4)` from the client and read in the first 4 bytes of the message and then call `int messageLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(message)` but you would need to start worrying about [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) when you start working with multi-byte numbers. ([`BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) always returns `true` on the windows desktop but it could be different on mobile platforms)

Comment: Yeah wanted to but i couldn't as the time limit wasn't up yet. Did it now